# Why is this jQuery reference '$("<div />")' instead of '$("<div></div>")'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
popup =
$("<div />")
.css(settings.popupCSS)
.attr("id", settings.popupId)
.css("position", "absolute")
.appendTo("body").hide();
```

I'm reading some jQuery code and I'm a bit confused as to what `$("<div />")` means. Is it just referring to the `<div />` instance that's popping up at that moment?

Comment: That div element is invalid, btw.

Comment: I'd say, have a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2). `<div/>` and `<div></div>` are treated the same, but the first one is shorter.

Comment: divs are technically not supposed to self close, but it doesn't render that way. So it doesn't matter because, when it comes down to it, it's just a string.

Comment: Do you see a self-closing div? I don't. I see a string passed to the jQuery function, which may or may not get built as a self-closing div later. It's an implementation detail. $('<div>') doesn't produce an invalid DOM structure, for example, so investigation into a specific version of jQuery would be required to make a statement like "the div element is invalid."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically it doesn't matter if you use `$('<div />')` or `$('<div></div>')`.

What this code is doing is creating a new div element, adding some css styles to it, adding an id, positioning it, appending it to the body and then hiding it.

I'm guessing jQuery uses document.createElement to create the element and that means the browser knows how to render it.

Comment: he is not asking what is the code doing.. his question was what is the difference

Comment: You can also use `$('<div>')`. jQuery figures out you want a new element without needing the closing tag. Who downvoted this and why?

Comment: @zzzz: I'm not sure you fully understand the question, or any of us do. It *almost* sounds like he's asking what the whole code group means. "The div that's popping up at the moment" would indicate he didn't know that the syntax was creating new elements.

Comment: @Stefan: indeed... jQuery is smart like that... :P

Comment: **title**: Why is this jQuery reference '$("<div />")' instead of '$("<div></div>")'

Comment: @Stefan: You should not use `$('<div>')`. The documentation says, for cross-browser compatibility, elements which can contain other elements should be either self-closed or provided with a closing tag.

Comment: @Felix King: Show me one example where using `$('<div>')` causes breakage. Documentation lies.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery allows you to use `$("<p><em>Your</em> HTML here!</p>")` to create a new HTML element, which you can later insert into the document (using `.append()`, for example).

`<div />` is the XML/XHTML syntax for a "self-closing" element (one which doesn't require a closing tag). In this case, it's equivalent to using `<div></div>`. `<div>` isn't normally supposed to be self-closing, but jQuery supports it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It is same as `<div></div>`. It does not matter which one you'll use

Answer (score 2):

A `$("<element />")` creates a new element of that type that is unattached to the DOM (document object model).  Once they're done setting up the div they'll almost certainly be adding it to the document later on.  As other users have already said, the use of `<div></div>` or `<div />` doesn't matter in this case as both will create a new empty div element.

Comment: $('<element>') is also valid.

Answer (score 1):

`$("<div />")` is creating a new div tag as a jQuery object and assigning it to the `popup` variable.  The rest is applying the style settings, `id` and adding it to the `<body></body>` with `display: none`.

If you were to write out the html for the div tag it would read: `<div id="{value of settings.popupId}" style="{value of settings.popupCSS}; position:relative;"></div>`

The appendTo, adds it to the body and the hide makes it hidden:

```
<body>
    <div id="{value of settings.popupId}" style="{value of settings.popupCSS}; position:relative; display:none;"></div>
</body>
```