# Why do people use slashes when creating elements?

Tags: jquery

When people create elements with jQuery I always see them do something along the lines of `$(<div />)`. Why? As far as I can tell `$('<div>')` works just as well. Am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is this jQuery reference '$("<div />")' instead of '$("<div></div>")'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296219/why-is-this-jquery-reference-div-instead-of-div-div)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It never matters.

jQuery (eventually) applies the following regular expression to decide if the string you passed is a "single tag":

```
/^<(\w+)\s*\/?>(?:<\/\1>)?$/
```

If the string you pass matches this regex, jQuery simply takes the subpattern `(\w+)` (the tag name), and passes it to `document.createElement()`.

`<div>`, `<div />`, `<div/>` and `<div></div>` all match this pattern, so they're all handled exactly the same: as `createElement('div')`.

Comment: This totally led to a few minutes of me playing in the console to see what else might work.

Comment: Funny enough, this means that `<div/></div>` will also work though completely incorrect.  Its important to note that any string that any HTML string that doesn't match this pattern will be loaded via `innerHTML`.  This applies to `<div class="foobar"/>` and `<div><b></b></div>`.  In this case, proper tag closing is required for container elements.

Answer (score 4):

It's the syntax for a self-closing tag. A `<div>` should not be self-closing, but in this case it makes no difference. jQuery supports it, and it gets rendered the same way.

```
$("<div>")       // = <div></div>
$("<div />")     // = <div></div>
$("<div></div>") // = <div></div>
```

See this SO question for more details:
[Why is this jQuery reference '$("<div />")' instead of '$("<div></div>")'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296219/why-is-this-jquery-reference-div-instead-of-div-div)

Comment: Right, I know about self-closing tags. My question is when does it _ever_ make a difference whether you include the slash or not?

Comment: To my knowledge it doesn't make a difference. I think jQuery just interprets it the same way to provide a little more flexibility.

Comment: Ok then, from now on, unless there is good reason, we just use the simplest version possible - `$('<div>')` - Who's with me?

Answer (score 3):

No you're not missing anything. jQuery will happily take that and render the appropriate tag. I think where a lot of people get tripped up is that the docs suggest you use a XHTML compatible element.

However, what some people seem to miss is that jQuery does not pass that directly to `document.createElement()`. Rather, it runs a regex on it (or at least did last time I checked) and figures out what to actually pass to `document.createElement()`.

What that suggests to me, is that there is no right or wrong way to create an element, as really, you're passing a string representation of some HTML element. Mr. Resig could have just as easily used `$('div');` or `$('HTML:DIV');` or whatever he felt like at the time. Instead, he chose to use "HTML like string that will be translated correctly by this regex into actual HTML", and as such all of the following are equally valid:

```
$('<div>');
$('<div/>');
$('<div></div>');
```

... and are valid not because they may or may not be XHTML compliant, but because the regex used is able to turn that into a proper HTML element.

Answer (score 1):

It ensures cross-browser compatibility.  Some browsers may fail if container elements are not closed `<div></div>` or quick closed `<div />`.  It is unnecessary for non-container elements `<img>`

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2 for details.

**Correction**

For `<div></div>`, `<div/>`, and `<div>`, jQuery parses it and uses document.createElement.  For anything more complicated, like `<div style="display:none" />` or `<div><b></b></div>`, it will use innerHTML to create the element.  In this case, proper tag closing and nesting are required for container elements and optional for non-container elements.  If they are excluded, the code could fail on some browsers.

Since you may at some point add attributes or child elements to an HTML string, it would probably be a best practice to always use a tag closing practice to avoid unexpected bugs.

Comment: That's for HTML, but I don't think that's true for jQuery, see the other answers - it parses out the element to be created.

Comment: Thanks George, I read more closely and for simple elements without attributes it does indeed use createElement.  For anything more complex it uses innerHTML and requires proper tag closing.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<div></div>` or simply `<div/>`. They are both the same. The last one is less verbose.

Here is some documentation about closing tag : [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html). See 3.2.1

Same thing in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html). See 8.1.2.2.

In Html, you need to close you tag. You have two ways to do it.

Comment: but isn't `$('<div>')' even LESS verbose?

Comment: Yes but if you do, the HTML tag is not closed. In html, a tag is closed with it has <TAG/> or <TAG></TAG>.

Comment: Open up your console and type `$('<div>').append('<div>').html()` - it will output `"<div></div>"`